# How to select certain pattern in an array

Tags: ruby

Here is my array:

```
a = ['a','b','c', 'C!', 'D!']
```

I would like to select any upcase letters followed by the `!` character and display them. I was trying:

```
puts a.select! {|i|  i.upcase + "!"}
```

which gave me null set. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @CarySwoveland That doesn't take into consideration whether the string is followed by `!`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Though it does not fit this question, your approach is interesting.

Answer (score 5):

```
puts a.grep(/[A-Z]!/)
```

will do.

Comment: What `!` is doing there.. Poor concept I have in _RegEx_.

Comment: Ohh! Yes.. I see now. I thought it is a Regex part. +1 for using `#grep`.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

`a.select {|i| i =~ /[A-Z]!/}`

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way using the Regexp match method in Ruby.

```
a.select { |letter| /[A-Z]!/.match(letter) }
```

Also, one note: consider a more meaningful and contextually relevant variable name than "i" in *a.select! {|i|  i.upcase + "!"}*.  For example, I chose the name "letter", although there may be a more meaningful name.  It's just a good naming practice that a lot of Ruby programmers tend to follow.  Same thing applies to the array named *a*.